# I'm getting the following error message: ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis

Tags: python, pandas, valueerror

Why am I getting this error message? My code:

```
my_df.loc[my_df['col1'] < my_df['col2'],'col3'] = my_df['col1'].
```

Basically what I'm trying to do is set col3 equal to col1 whenever col3 is less than col2. Thanks!

Comment: Because `my_df` has duplicated index and  pandas does not know how to align them?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by a 'duplicated index'? Do you mean that the dataframe's index has repeat values in it?

Comment: Yes, duplicated == repeated. Do a `df.index.duplicated().sum()` to check.

Comment: can you test? `my_df.loc[my_df['col1'] < my_df['col2'],'col3'] = my_df.loc[my_df['col1'] < my_df['col2'],'col1']`

Comment: Can you check if my answer is correct? :)

Comment: I don't think that would have worked. The issue was that the dataframe's index needed to be reset using the reset_index() function. There were rows with identical indexes value due to a concat function I had used in a prior calculation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by resetting the index on the dataframes with reset_index(). The index got "messed up" due to a prior concat function.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to look like you are trying to insert different data sizes. Column **col3** must be the same size of **col1**.
 Try this:

```
my_df.loc[my_df['col1'] < my_df['col2'],'col3'] = my_df.loc[my_df['col1'] < my_df['col2'],'col1']
```